# How to use Glassfish 7 with eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, glassfish

I try to start an application using glassfish 7 on eclipse.

But I don't find how to add the server in window --> preferences --> server --> runtime environnements
When i click on add, glassfish is not in the list ><

[image]

Do you know how to do it ?

I want to start an application with eclipse and glassfish 7.
I can't find how to add glassfish in eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

For any Eclipse version starting from 2022-03 (4.23) you can download from the Eclipse Marketplace [OmniFish tools](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/omnifish-tools-eclipse-glassfish), since Glassfish tools doesn't seem to be maintained and does not support Glassfish 7.

Also note that you need to download [Glassfish 7](https://glassfish.org/download).

After you install OmniFish tools and restart Eclipse you can find the 'Glassfish' option when you create a new Runtime Environment. From there you just  need to indicate the Glassfish 7 path you just downloaded.